# Windows 8.1 update2 on a Nokia Lumia 830

Tags: 8.1

The spell checker doesn't seem to be working.  I've tried to turn it on and off but i get no alternative suggestions or highlights to say a word is spelt incorrectly.  Can anyone help?
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1):

I had this awhile back, the Keyboard language was ENG(US) rather than ENG (GB) for me. I would just double check that the language is set correctly

EDIT: This might prove useful http://www.digitalcitizen.life/add-new-keyboard-languages-windows-phone-8-switch-between-them